# AIR App, load swf from server, call parent function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

At the end of each child swf I want to trigger within the AIR app that they are done playing.

I have been able to add within the AIR app document class that loads these an event listener (Enter Frame) but that chews up cpu.

Am I able to do it the other way? Here is my attempt at customEvents but nothing fires.

Any ideas?

CustomEvent.as

```
package com.net {

import flash.events.*;

public class CustomEvent extends Event {
    // define variables
    public static const GOTEM:String = "gotEm";

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    //in case of redispatch
    public override function clone():Event{
        return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
}
```

Within AIR APP:

```
stage.addEventListener("gotEm", swfFinished);
```

Within Child SWF:

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.GOTEM));
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of listening to `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, you could dispatch a custom event from within your child swf:

`dispatchEvent(new Event("childComplete"));`

Then you'd listen for only that event in your AIR app.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible... I am getting an error 2047 when trying to reference the parent (air app) and its functions from external swfs that are being played.

Comment: You shouldn't have to access the parent app from the external SWFs. All you have to do is dispatch that even from inside of the external SWF. Then, in your parent app, you listen for the event. At what point are you getting the error?

Comment: Well... just for sanity sake because nothing was firing.  I added a simple text field on stage of the child swf being played and was trying to reference the parent of it.  Then getting an error.  Does my customEvent.as look proper?

Comment: Do you have the same `com.net.CustomEvent` in both the source paths of the external SWF and of the AIR app? If not, try adding it, _or_ change your listener to listen to the string `"gotEm"` instead of `CustomEvent.GOTEM`.

Comment: It also depends on what the target of the event is. Where are you dispatching? Try dispatching it from the `stage` (`stage.dispatchEvent(...)`), _or_ you can try bubbling the event (setting the default value of `bubbles` to true).

Comment: yep same for both builds.  ill try the latter you mentioned.  Only change the listener or the dispatch too?  dispatchEvent(new Event("gotEm")); and addEventListener("gotEm", swfFinished); ?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try it with just the listener listening for the string. But I think the real issue is that it's not being dispatched from the correct location and that it's not bubbling. Therefore, the parent is not receiving the event.

Comment: Thanks again Marcela.  I updated the initial post (above) with your suggestions and now getting an error 2070 about referencing the parent stage. :/

Comment: Instead of dispatching form stage, try dispatching from the document class of the external SWF